# c# xamarin - Android background service closing when I close application

Tags: c#, android

My Android service closing when I close the main activity. 
I tried add to the AndroidManifest.xml: `<service android:name="App7.SimpleService" android:stopWithTask="false">`

I also tried the following code for starting service:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(SimpleService));
 StartService(intent2);
```

and

```
 StartService(new Intent("App7.SimpleService"));
```

I tried also the `return START_STICKY;` and `return StartCommandResult.Sticky;`, but no effects.

My code:
**SimpleService.cs:**

```
    using System;
using System.Threading;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Android.Widget;
using Android;
using App7;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;

namespace SimpleService
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new String[] { "App7.SimpleService" })]
    public class SimpleServiceBinder : Service
    {


        public static StartCommandResult START_STICKY { get; private set; }




        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
        /// My service code
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
   //         binder = new SimpleService(this);
           return null;
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {


        base.OnDestroy();




        }


    }
}
```

**MainActivity.cs:**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using App7;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using Android.Webkit;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SimpleService
{
    [Activity(Label = "aplikacja1", MainLauncher = true)]
    [Service]

    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

                //////////////////////////////////////
                this.StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(SimpleServiceBinder)));
               /// I tried also////

              // Intent intent2 = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(SimpleService));
                //  StartService(intent2);
               // StartService(new Intent("App7.SimpleService"));



        }
    }
}
```

Please, help me